# Pull custom fields from custom posts within a loop

Tags: custom-field, custom-post-types

This is going to sound a little nuts. I have a situation where I'm displaying a list of products that a user selects to move to the products' page. I also have documents and videos that I created custom post types and fields for. I need to run a second loop within the current loop to pull a custom field from a custom post type. If that makes sense?

for example this is the product "directory" loop (pardon my hackish techniques)

```
<div id="content" role="main">
<?php 
    $parent = $post->ID; 
    query_posts('post_type=page&order=ASC&orderby=title&post_parent='.$parent);?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php $model = get_the_title(); ?>
<div class="product-selection-container round">
    <h2 class="directory-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "product-main-title", true); ?></a></h2>
    <h3>Model <?php echo $model ?></h3><!-- the model -->
    <?php echo my_excerpts(); ?>
    <ul class="round">
        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">Learn More</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Specification Sheet</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Video Tour</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

And this is the loop I generally use to add documents to the pages (excluding the custom loop template)

```
<?php
        $documents = array('numberposts' => 5, 'post_type' => 'documents', 'category_name' => $model);
        query_posts( $documents );
        get_template_part( 'loop', 'documents' );
        wp_reset_query();
 ?>
```

I tried combining the two where I would add the second loop to `<li><a href="">Specification Sheet</a></li>` but that caused the page to run in a perpetual loop.

An alternative option I was looking for was to pull a single custom field from a post type without creating a loop. For example.

```
get post_type => document, meta_key => document-type, meta_value => spec-sheet
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at the loop docs on the codex, for nested loops or multiple loops on same page don't use query_posts, use something like $my_query = new WP_Query .

Comment: Yeah I've been having a tough time converting my current loops o get_posts or WP_Query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll presume you are using something like this...to get the custom value you want. Once you are inside the loop.

```
$customfieldvalue = get_post_meta($post->ID, "metakeyname", true);
```

Since you are using $model as the base for a query. You could create a function That will query what you want, and then reset the current query. You could use it wherever you want. Here is a template.

```
function modelquery($model) {
    global $wp_query, $post, $paged, $post_count;

        // YOUR QUERY
        $query_args = array (
            'numberposts' => 5, 
            'post_type' => 'documents', 
            'category_name' => $model
        );    

        // SAVE CURRENT QUERY
        $temp = $wp_query;
        $wp_query= null;    

        // CREATE NEW QUERY
        $wp_query = new WP_Query();
        $wp_query->query($query_args);      

        // THE LOOP, DO WHAT YOU HAVE TO DO HERE
        while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();    
            $customfieldvalue = get_post_meta($post->ID, "metakeyname", true);
            echo $customfieldvalue;
        endwhile;   

        // SWAP BACK THE PREVIOUS QUERY
        $wp_query = null; 
        $wp_query = $temp;
        wp_reset_query();       


}
```